# Login and Logout AD with C#

Tags: active-directory, authentication, logout

How can i login without logout from current user to another Active Directory user with C#. ;
1-Getting new user's access 
2- doing my work and than logout with c# same way.

For example i am a user at blabla.com domain.I have logged in a Power User.But i need Admin Rights for something so i need to logout and change user to Administrator do my job and relogin with Power User again.I wanna do it with C#.

I heard something like that Impersonate User but i think this is not what i want.

Edited : I want login with another user and get this user's permissions without logout from my current user in c#.

Comment: Do you want to do something like Vista does with raising permissions to perform certain tasks?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. If what you want to be doing is querying/modifying AD, then t4zsan's answer is correct.

If you just need the other user's groups/security permissions, then Impersonation is the way to go.  [This article will give you a good foundation on it](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx).

Caveats:  The user you wish to impersonate must be able to logon to the machine you are running the code on.  You can't impersonate a user in another domain if that domain is not trusted. Nor can you impersonate a local user on another machine, obviously.

Comment: I want login with another user from C# without logout from current user.

Comment: Impersonation makes the current running process look like it is running as the user ID impersonated.  If you want a full login kicked off from your process, I'm not sure how that would be done.

Answer (score 1):

When using the classes in System.DirectoryServices to connect to AD you have the option of specifying user credentials.  For example when using DirectoryEntry there is a [constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh2h7eed.aspx) taking username and password that lets you connect as a different user.